# similar to groupByKey() in Spark but using SQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I trying to make

```
 ID    CATEGORY  VALUE
'AAA'    'X'      123
'AAA'    'Y'      456
'BBB'    'X'      321
'BBB'    'Y'      654
```

into

```
 ID     VALUE_X   VALUE_Y
'AAA'     123       456
'BBB'     321       654
```

using only SQL queries.
It is kind of similar to using groupByKey() in pyspark.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation.  One method is:

```
select id,
       max(case when category = 'X' then value end) as x_value,
       max(case when category = 'Y' then value end) as y_value
from t
group by id;
```

In Postgres, this would be phrased using the standard `filter` clause:

```
select id,
       max(value) filter (where category = 'X'),
       max(value) filter (where category = 'Y')
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Why do we need a max?

Comment: @jginso7 . . . You need an aggregation function and `max()` is convenient because it works on all types.

Comment: Hi just an additional question... What is some IDs don't have VALUE for a CATEGORY? Say, ID 'CCC' only has CATEGORY of 'X' VALUE '123', but no other rows. For that I want ```CCC  123  0```

Comment: If there is no key, the value is `NULL`.  You can wrap the expression in `coalesce()`:  `coalesce(max(value) filter (where category = 'Y'), 0)`.